# Summation of a set of vectors in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am trying to sum up a set of vectors in Prolog.

I have the code for summing up the elements in one vector but I am not sure how to extend it to multiple vectors.

I have this:

```
set_addtion([],0).   
set_addtion([Head | Tail], TotalSum) :-
  set_addtion(Tail, Sum1),
  TotalSum is Head + Sum1.
```

Answer (score 2):

In SWI Prolog, with [`sum_list/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=sum_list/2) and [`maplist/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/3) that's a simple composition:

```
sum_vectors(Vectors,Sum):-
  maplist(sum_list,Vectors,Sums),
  sum_list( ... , ... ).           % fill in the blanks!
```

That's assuming that `Vectors` is a list of lists of numbers.

---

Concerning your code - it isn't [*tail-recursive*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call). It is much better to write code that *is* TR, the stack use will be constant. To achieve TR, usually it means *don't delay for later what you can do right away*. Here, you're delaying the addition of `Head`, until the `Sum1` is found out - but that will be much much later, when all the rest of the list is consumed.

But what do we have that we can add `Head` to, right away? Well, we could have `SumSoFar`, and add to *that*. Then this new variable would serve as an accumulator, its initial value - `0`. The accumulator transformation is a standard way to achieve TR.

Answer (score 1):

if you need to handle *nested* lists - maybe the result of some tree structured computation - you could do using these builtins:

```
sum_lists(Nested, Total) :-
   flatten(Nested, List),
   sum_list(List, Total).
```